# Why is single_cmd Alsa option for debugging only?

Tags: sound, alsa, codecs, hda-intel

According to Alsa documentation, single_cmd option is for debugging only :

> single_cmd  - Use single immediate commands to communicate with
>         codecs (for debugging only)
>
> NB: If you get many "azx_get_response timeout" messages at loading,
>   it's likely a problem of interrupts (e.g. ACPI irq routing).  Try to
>   boot with options like "pci=noacpi".  Also, you can try "single_cmd=1"
>   module option.  This will switch the communication method between HDA
>   controller and codecs to the single immediate commands instead of
>   CORB/RIRB.  Basically, the single command mode is provided only for
>   BIOS, and you won't get unsolicited events, too.  But, at least, this
>   works independently from the irq.  Remember this is a last resort, and
>   should be avoided as much as possible...

https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/sound/alsa/ALSA-Configuration.txt

This option seems to make my system more stable.

Why this option should be use for debugging only?
Is there any risks of using single_cmd as a usual parameter?

Answer (score 0):

There is no risk as far as the sound driver itself is concerned.

However, "azx_get_response timeout" messages are just symptoms caused by a problems with interrupts, and those interrupt problems are very likely to cause errors in other places. Using `single_cmd` cannot affect any of those other errors.
If at all possible, you should try to fix those interrupt problems.